# Loading resources from another maven module with mvn exec:java doesn't work

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project with this structure:

```
parent
-----module1
--------src
------------main
-----------------java
----------------------Loader.java
-----------------resources
-------------------------file1.txt
-----module2
--------src
------------main
-----------------java
-------------------------CallLoader.java
```

So `Loader.java`, loads `files1.txt`. I call this class from `CallLoader.java` from module2. This is the code I used

In `Loader.java`,

```
private static File getResourceFile(String fileName){
        try {
            URL resource = GraphUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResource(fileName);
            return new File(resource.getPath());
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't load resource: "+fileName, e);
        }
}
```

where `fileName="file1.txt"`.

I get an error because the file absolute path looks like this:

```
file:/home/moha/.m2/repository/my/package/name/%7Bproject.version%7D/base-%7Bproject.version%7D.jar!/file1.txt
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you need to load the resource in module2 why not moving the resource to module 2 cause it sounds like it belongs there...

Comment: @khmarbaise module3 uses the same resources. I excluded mentioning it because it's out scope.

Comment: Sounds like there is an architectural dept in there ... ?

Comment: @khmarbaise, I am not sure if I understand you well but I really want to know. Would you please elaborate?

Comment: A resource should be handled at a single point. So other modules should depend on a class which provids this information but other classes shouldn't load the resources themselfs. Sounds like a violation of separation of concern. So going to your example only a single class will really load the resources (via .getResourcesAsStream()) and will provide it within a interface. Other classes (modules) will only use the interface....Otherwise you are writing the code for loading the resources several times (violating DRY)...

Comment: @khmarbaise. That's what I'm doing. Both `module2` and `module3` call `Loader@module1` to load `file1.txt@module1`. Isn't this correct?

Comment: In resources you shouldn't work with File you should use getResourceAsStream("/file1.txt"); and that will be done in a initalization method of LoaderModule. The loader Module provided a method to get the information (lazy initialization). This sounds like a singleton...And doing it that way you only have have to resource in the Loader module nowhere else...May be you can provide a full working example (only reduced to the important parts) so we have something more specific to talk about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the content of your file as a stream instead in order to be able to read your resource from a jar file which is the root cause of your issue. In other words use `getResourceAsStream` instead of `getResource`.

You can also return the `URL` instead of `File` then call `openStream()` later to read it if needed.

`NB1:` the URL will be of type `jar:file/...` which cannot be managed by the class `File`

`NB2:` To convert a `URL` into a `File`, the correct code is `new File(resource.toURI())`